# Making rubygem - Error: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, scripting, build, rubygems, centos

I'm currently attempting to create a ruby gem out of a script and, while it works if I take the scripts and put them in the same directory, if I put them in the appropriate /bin and /lib directories after generating my gem structure, build the gem and then attempt to execute it I'm given the uninitialized constant error. Under /bin the relevant section in the file "cjp" is:

```
Cjb.new(crontabDir, logDir, allowedFrequency, printOnly, testRun).
    find_violations autoFix
```

The class is defined in the file cjp.rb under /lib

```
class Cjb
  def initialize(crontabDir, logDir, allowedFrequency, printOnly, testRun)
    @crontabDir, @logDir, @allowedFrequency, @printOnly, @testRun =
      crontabDir, logDir, allowedFrequency, printOnly, testRun
```

Despite this, the error I get is:

```
ERROR:  uninitialized constant Cjb
```

I also noticed that if I attempt to manually execute the "cjp" script under /bin without the lib script being in the same directory that it also gives the same error. It appears that I'm missing something.

Any help on what I'm missing here to get this working would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your gem?

Comment: The name of the gem is simply "cjp". I generated the structure with: bundle gem cjp -b. FYI, if I try to change the name of the cjp.rb file I'm unable to build it as it states that ["lib/cjp.rb"] are not files.

Comment: `bundle gem` uses git to manage gem manifest. Do you see all your expected files when you run `git ls-files` in your gem project dir?

Comment: No, I don't. How do I fix that? I basically just have two files: cjp in bin and cjp.rb in lib that need to be loaded.

Comment: Added as answer, as I think it's the cause of your problem.

Comment: ok, apparently not the whole answer. Could you add how you are requiring the library code in your script (I would expect to see `require "cjp"` if your class is defined in the file `lib/cjp.rb`). Also I noticed you have **Cjb** for class name and **cjp** for gem name - is there possibly a file or require where you have got the "b" and "p" muddled?

Comment: As far as I can tell the class isn't incorrect. I've copied everything over to pastebin so you can take a looksee. Bin file: http://pastebin.com/1pyniSBQ Lib file: http://pastebin.com/pHV0U8fC

Comment: @Striketh: You have `require 'cjp'` inside the library file, but not in the bin file. That needs to be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle gem` uses git to manage gem manifest.

If you do not see all your expected files when you run `git ls-files` in your gem project dir, then you need to add them.

To add individual files:

```
git add <filename>
```

To add everything (run from root of project):

```
git add .
```

This may have caught you out if you were not expecting to use `git` on your project. If you don't know git, and have time, it is really recommended to help you manage your project code. In fact so much so that `bundle` simply assumes that's what you want to do (although other code management tools are available)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I regenerated the structure, copied my code over to /bin and /lib and git listed the correct files (I made sure with the git ls-files command) but the gem, after being built and installed, continues to give me the error "ERROR:  uninitialized constant Cjb" so I'm guessing there's an issue with the code somewhere.